# Geometric Coset

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am familiar with cosets, but im not sure what to do here (never had to give a "geometric" description of a coset):

Consider $\mathbb{R}$ and the subgroup $\mathbb{Z}$.

Describe a coset $t+\mathbb{Z}$ geometrically and show the set of all cosets of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is $\{t+\mathbb{Z} : 0\leq t< 1\}$

Im lost, I suppose I dont understand cosets enough to put them into geometric terms..I suppose I just view them as abstract objects in groups.

Any help would be great!

Comment: They are translations of $\mathbb{Z}$. Pictorially, they are a ruler (that only sees centimeters) moving around.

Comment: You can imagine $\mathbb Z$ as an homogeneous grid of points on the line. Adding $t$ moves all of them to the left or to the right by the same distance. Eventually, they will overlap their initial configuration!

Comment: The most geometric way I can think of off-hand would be to think of the set of cosets of $\mathbb{Z}$ as a circle (since $t+1+\mathbb{Z}=t+\mathbb{Z}$ for every $t\in\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: Is there any actual math involved here?  How could I show that t needs to be greater than or equal to zero and less than 1?

Comment: Its not that it *needs* to be. Notice that adding integers preserves the coset, so, for example, adding 1.1 would have the same effect on the coset than adding 0.1. (This geometrically means that you moved the grid to the right until it overlapped its initial configuration and then 0.1 more past that)

Comment: @ThePhysicsStudent Were you able to solve it?

Comment: Sidenote, how are you embedding images like that? Do note that Mathjax is an option, so that `$\{t + \Bbb Z : 0 \le t < 1 \}$` will produce the homogeneously typeset $\{t + \Bbb Z : 0 \le t < 1 \}$